# How can I limit what data is entered in SQL Server?

Tags: sql, sql-server

For example: I have a column named Software, where I want only 2 entries either Hotel or Restro. Besides these two;Hotel and Restro, the column should not allow other data. I am trying to implement this database in Hotel Managemnet System through ASP.NET. So, is it possible in anyway in SQL Server?

Comment: in this case you can use check constraint https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/tables/create-check-constraints?view=sql-server-ver16

Comment: Your title reads like content that should be in your question, and your title should be different

Answer (score 0):

You may use a check constraint in the create table definition:

```sql
CREATE TABLE yourTable (
    Id INT IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY,
    some_col VARCHAR(6) NOT NULL CHECK (some_col IN ('Hotel', 'Restro'))
    -- rest of definition here
);
```